# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode = 0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber: Bool = false

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!

        if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber) {
            label.text = label.text! + digit
        }
        else {
            label.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = true
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently creating a calculator app. For some reason, when I run the simulator and try to input some digits in, the siumulator freezes, and the error of bad_instruction appears on the line:

```
label.text = digit
```

How would I fix this situation?

Comment: Can you post the whole error log ?

Comment: Is "digit" a string?

Comment: To learn how to debug a crash, please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: If this is an "unexpectedly found nil" crash – then also see [this extensive Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) on the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to connect the label in the Storyboard with the outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `currentTitle` property is `nil` which results in a crash. You are force unwrapping the property without any `nil` check.

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    if let digit = sender.currentTitle {
        if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber) {
            label.text = label.text! + digit
        }
        else {
            label.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = true
        }
    }
}
```

OR

It could be the reason specified by @dasdom